# How much of the map is cached when using the google map apis and for how long?

Tags: android, caching, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing an android application which is using the google maps api to render maps. I would like to inform the users how much of their bandwidth is expected to be used by the application, but I am unable to find any information about how the cache works.

Is there a limit to how much map data the application will store in its cache?
How long will the data remain in the cache?

Comment: do you find any answer for this??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this information is disclosed by Google but I'd dig into https://developers.google.com/maps/terms.